# R: Visualizing accuracy (inter-rater) on continuous data

Tags: r, data-visualization, accuracy, agreement-statistics, precision

Please excuse my english, I'm not a native speaker.

So I'm running a test-retest scenario to determine accuracy of my measurements of continuous data (angles [deg] and length [mm]). I've calculated "deltas" for both raters from the first set of results:

```
orig_result1 - raterA_result1 = delta_raterA_1
orig_result2 - raterA_result2 = delta_raterA_2
...
```

this leads to the following table:

```
as.table(ratings)

  raterA raterB
A  -1.0   1.0
B   1.0   3.0
C  -5.0  -2.0
D  -2.0   1.0
E   1.0  -2.0
F  -4.0  -6.0
G   0.0   2.0
...
```

Question: How do I best visualize this data in r?

I'm thinking of a "target" with the bulls-eye at 0,0 and plotting each value for raterA and raterB with different colors around it, but I can't figure out a way to do this with dotplot(), dotchart() or qplot().

Any ideas? 
Thanks so much!

Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test-retest-data I generally advise a look at mean-difference plot, also known as Bland-Altman-Plots. Please see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BlandAltmanLeh/index.html and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BlandAltmanLeh/vignettes/Intro.html

Your bulls-eye-plot can simply be started with plot(). Circles can be added via the plotrix package.

```
d <- read.table(text="  raterA raterB
           A  -1.0   1.0
           B   1.0   3.0
           C  -5.0  -2.0
           D  -2.0   1.0
           E   1.0  -2.0
           F  -4.0  -6.0
           G   0.0   2.0")
plot(jitter(d$raterA), jitter(d$raterB), col=1:7, xlim=c(-7,7), 
 ylim=c(-7,7), xlab="rater A", ylab = "rater B", pch=16)
abline(h=0, col="grey")
abline(v=0, col="grey")
```